# Error: Unhandled Promise rejection in AngularJS 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm building a Angular Provider that uses http to get data from The Movie DataBase Api.

But, although, i'm getting this errors in the page that i'm using that provider:
[image]

So, the source code of the provider and page is:

**tmdb.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()

export class TMDB {
  apiUrl: string = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3";
  apiKey: string = "xxx";
  apiLang: string = "pt-BR";

  posterLargePath: string = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500_and_h281_bestv2";
  posterMiniPath: string = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w116_and_h174_bestv2";

  constructor(public http: Http) {
  }

  getSearchMovie(query: string){
    let body = {"api_key":this.apiKey, "language":this.apiLang, "query":query, "include_adult": false};
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + "/search/movie?" + JSON.stringify(body), options)
            .map((res:Response) => res.json())
            .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
    }

  getDiscoverMovies(){
    let body = {"api_key":this.apiKey, "language":this.apiLang, "page":1, "sort_by":"popularity.desc", "include_video": false, "include_adult": false};
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
     return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + "/discover/movie?" + JSON.stringify(body), options)
            .map((res:Response) => res.json())
            .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
  }

  getPosterLargeUrl(){
    return this.posterLargePath;
  }

  getPosterMiniUrl(){
    return this.posterMiniPath;
  }

}
```

**page.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
//import{ Http } from '@angular/http';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
//import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import { TMDB } from '../../providers/tmdb.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
  //,providers: [TMDB]
})
export class HomePage {
  discoverMovies: any;
  posterMiniPath: string;
  posterLargePath: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    TMDB.getDiscoverMovies().subscribe(
                              movies => this.discoverMovies = movies, //Bind to view
                              err => {
                                  // Log errors if any
                                  console.log(err);
                              });
    this.posterMiniPath = TMDB.getPosterMiniUrl();
    this.posterLargePath = TMDB.getPosterLargeUrl();
  }

}
```

I need to know that is the bug. Can someone help me? Remembering that i'm using Ionic Framework v. 2.

**Edit 1:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { TMDB } from '../../providers/tmdb.ts';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html',
  providers: [TMDB]
})
export class HomePage {
  discoverMovies: any;
  posterMiniPath: string;
  posterLargePath: string;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public tmdb: TMDB) {
    tmdb.getDiscoverMovies().subscribe(
                              movies => this.discoverMovies = movies,
                              err => {
                                  console.log(err);
                              });
    this.posterMiniPath = tmdb.getPosterMiniUrl();
    this.posterLargePath = tmdb.getPosterLargeUrl();
  }

}
```

**Edit 2:**

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { PageIntro } from '../pages/intro/page';
import { TMDB } from '../providers/tmdb.ts';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    PageIntro
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    PageIntro
  ],
  providers: [ TMDB ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

tmdb.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';

/*
  Generated class for the TMDB provider.

  See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html
  for more info on providers and Angular 2 DI.
*/
@Injectable()

export class TMDB {
  apiUrl: string = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3";
  apiKey: string = "xxxx";
  apiLang: string = "pt-BR";

  posterLargePath: string = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500_and_h281_bestv2";
  posterMiniPath: string = "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w116_and_h174_bestv2";

  constructor(public http: Http) {
  }

  getSearchMovie(query: string){
    let body = {"api_key":this.apiKey, "language":this.apiLang, "query":query, "include_adult": false};
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + "/search/movie?" + JSON.stringify(body), options)
            .map((res:Response) => res.json())
            .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
    }

  getDiscoverMovies(){
    let body = {"api_key":this.apiKey, "language":this.apiLang, "page":1, "sort_by":"popularity.desc", "include_video": false, "include_adult": false};
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
     return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + "/discover/movie?" + JSON.stringify(body), options)
            .map((res:Response) => res.json())
            .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'))
  }

  getPosterLargeUrl(){
    return this.posterLargePath;
  }

  getPosterMiniUrl(){
    return this.posterMiniPath;
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi, your screenshot is unreadable. btw please add the NgModule declaration to the topic, it may be usefull. On the other hand, you can't use the TMDB service without injecting the service. It may be the cause of your issue.

Comment: Image fixed and i did what you said but didn't fix the error.

Comment: Your screenshot confirmed my supposition. You have to inject TMBD before using it. You have to delcare it in your ngModule too. The answer below show you the right thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to call `TMDB.getDiscoverMovies` statically, when it is an *instance* method. What you should. What you should do, is add it to the `@NgModule.providers`, and then inject it into the `HomePage`

```
@NgModule({
  providers: [ TMDB ]
})
class AppModule {}

@Component({})
class HomePage {
  constructor(private tmdb: TMDB) {
    tmdb.getDiscoverMovies().subscribe(
        movies => this.discoverMovies = movies, //Bind to view
        err => console.log(err));
    this.posterMiniPath = tmdb.getPosterMiniUrl();
    this.posterLargePath = tmdb.getPosterLargeUrl();
  }
}
```

Notice we're using the `TMDB` as an *instance* now, and not statically.

Comment: I did what you said but i'm getting this error on `private tmdb: TMDB`: `Cannot find name 'TMDB'` and `Parameter 'tmdb' of constructor from exported class has or is using private name 'TMDB`. What's this?

Comment: You still need to `import { TMDB } from '../../providers/tmdb.ts';` into the class so you can use it (both in the module and the component class)

Comment: And please, check Edit 2.

Comment: Make sure you're importing it from the correct path

Comment: Other that that,  I don't know what could be causing that error. It didn't have it before, meaning the name is accessible

Comment: Fixed, cause import don't need the extension so: `import { TMDB } from '../../providers/tmdb'`. Thk you.